# Set Width of Expander to Fill Available Space

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `Listbox` of expander items and want them to fill the whole horizontal space available.

Here is a little example

```
<Window x:Class="ExpanderTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <ListBox>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Expander Background="Tan" 
                      HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="My Expander" 
                      ExpandDirection="Down" IsExpanded="True">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
                    adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut
                    labore et dolore magna aliqua
                </TextBlock>
            </Expander>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

If I set `Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}, Path=ActualWidth}"` on the `expander`, it behaves almost as I want it to, except that the expander is a little bit too wide.

Is there a way in xaml to tell the `ListBoxItem` or the `Expander` to fill all horizontal space available?

(if the width gets smaller, the hight should get larger accordingly to display the whole content)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, I found the solution, just add

```
ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
```

to the ListBox.